# JPA: How to get only certain children?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have some ManagedList which contains list of ListElement. Those ListElement contains a list of Translation.

```
public class ManagedList {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "managedList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ListElement> listElement;
}
public class ListElement {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name= "listElement_id")
    private List<ElementTranslation> translations;

}
public class ElementTranslation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Language language;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ListElement listElement;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = true, length = 200)
    private String text;

}
public class Language {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

}
```

I would like to get all ManagedList, with all their elements, but for each element I want only 1 translation (depending on locale selection)

Let say in DB I have 2 ManagedList, each one have 3 elements, each element has 2 translations.

With :

```
public List<ManagedList> findAllByOrderByNameAsc();
```

I got 2 results, but I got all translations for each Element.

I tried with :

```
@Query("select managedList from ManagedList managedList "
            + "left join managedList.listElement as listElement "
            + "left join listElement.translations as translations "
            + "left join  translations.language as language "
            + "where language.name = :locale ")
   List<ManagedList> getVocab(@Param("locale") String locale);
```

But I got 6 results, and anyway still each translation for each Element.

What I would like is to get 2 results (the ManagedList) with each of their Elements, and for each Element I would like only 1 translation (the one on  String locale).

I tried to add a "fetch" in the JPQL like

```
...
+ "left join fetch translations.language as language "
...
```

But I got the following error :

> query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched
>   association was not present in the select list

Any tips about how to achieve that?
Thx!

Comment: If you want only some translations, then translation must be in the select clause: `select managedList, translations ...`. A query doesn't return "partial entities". If you get the listElements of a ManagedList, you'll get all its elements, whetever the query used to get the managed list.

Comment: Ah so maybe my way is bad and I should get all DB results and filter only what I need during DTO mapping then

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify your model - change `Language` to an enum (your list of languages is limited, yeah?).

Then, try to add 'distinct' to your query and replace 'join' with 'join fetch':

```
@Query("select distinct " + 
        "  ml " +
        "from " + 
        "  ManagedList ml "
        "  join fetch ml.listElement le " +
        "  join fetch le.translations ts " +
        "where " + 
        "  ts.language = ?1")
List<ManagedList> getVocab(Language lang);
```